# Rsyslog doesn't send logs to logstash server on port

Tags: linux, rsyslog, logstash

I have two rsyslog-client and rsyslog-server. When I tried to "logger -p local1.notice SOMETHING" I don't see any information on server from one client, but from another I see logstash output.

I have copied rsyslog.conf, it's identical on these two servers. What's wrong?

When I test the connection via telnet x.x.x.x 10514 from problem server, telnet connection is ok and I see tcpdump logs. And when I change tcp listen logstash port to 514 all works properly.

When I do logger -p on problem client I don't see anything in tcpdump -i any on it.

But if I do the same thing on "OK" client I see outside traffic via tcpdump to port 10514 (or something different).

When I change logstash port to 514 problem solved.

```
[root@centos-25 ~]# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

$template DynFile,"/var/log/kibana/system-%HOSTNAME%.log"

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                ?DynFile


# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down


#### Logstash #####
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
local1.notice @@192.168.253.26:10514;json-template
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
$LocalHostName centos-25

# Include /var/log/dmesg for logging
$InputFileName /var/log/dmesg
$InputFileTag dmesg:
$InputFileStateFile stat-file1

$InputFileSeverity notice
$InputFileFacility local1
$InputRunFileMonitor
# end of include dmesg
```

This is test from OK client: logger -p local1.notice "test from problem centos-26"

Logstash output:

```
{
     "@timestamp" => "2017-07-04T10:43:55.121Z",
       "@version" => "1",
        "message" => "Test From Centos-26",
     "sysloghost" => "centos-26",
       "severity" => "notice",
       "facility" => "local1",
    "programname" => "root",
         "procid" => "-",
           "host" => "192.168.253.26",
           "port" => 40962,
           "type" => "rsyslog"
}
```

and this is from problem node: logger -p local1.notice "test from problem centos-25"

Nothing in output

rsyslog.conf is identical on these clients.

This is from OK client:

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

$template DynFile,"/var/log/kibana/system-%HOSTNAME%.log"

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                ?DynFile


# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down


#### Logstash #####
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
local1.notice @@192.168.253.26:10514;json-template
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
$LocalHostName centos-26

# Include /var/log/dmesg for logging
$InputFileName /var/log/dmesg
$InputFileTag dmesg:
$InputFileStateFile stat-file1

$InputFileSeverity notice
$InputFileFacility local1
$InputRunFileMonitor
# end of include dmesg
```

Comment: Does your rsyslog forwards/central syslog logs info level syslog messages?

Comment: Please add to the question your rsyslog.conf file.